# Change Eclipse settings to use 22.6.0

Tags: android, sdk, eclipse-plugin

Hi I have downgraded SDK to 22.6.0 but when I start eclipse it ask to update sdk how can i allow eclpse to use this downgraded version

Answer (score 0):

You can download new ADT bundle along with eclipse Juno [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). There is a bug in Eclipse ADT with upgrading so now they provided Eclipse Juno instead of ADT. You need to download the latest version. Sure this will solve your issue.